# Plugins folder not copied to android folder after using capacitor run android - Ionic 4

Tags: android, cordova, ionic4, capacitor

I installed the following lines below:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4
install @ionic-native/facebook
npx cap sync android
```

It generates a folder plugins/cordova-plugin-facebook4

But when I run the codes in the android studio emulator it always return

```
common.js:267 Native: tried calling Facebook.login, but the Facebook plugin is not installed.
common.js:279 Install the Facebook plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4'
```

I think the folder plugins did not copy to the android folder, any help thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the packages like this..

> npm install @ionic-native/facebook
>
> npm install cordova-plugin-facebook4
>
> ionic build
>
> npx cap sync android

then, follow these steps..

- In android studio, go to app -> res -> values -> string.xml
- add the following lines in resources

> ```
> <string name="fb_app_name"> YOUR FB APP NAME </string>
> <string name="fb_app_id"> YOUR FB APP ID </string>
> ```

To understand the last step, [follow this tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-cordova-plugins-that-require-install-variables-with-capacitor/), it is a bit outdated, but nevertheless great effort and explains a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To use the FB plugin, you first have to create a new Facebook App inside of the Facebook developer portal 
see this link: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook
and this for mor infos https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

Comment: check if it present in your plugins folder then run ionic cordova platform rm android and run ionic cordova prepare android you will find it in the folder platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/facebook

Comment: I did that before, but yes it generates a folder platform/android, but I already have have an android folder build with capacitor.